# Obtain Array Laravel ->first(); error json_decode() expects parameter

Tags: php, laravel

Hello for some strange reason I have an array obtained through a DB query in Laravel and I can't get the array

In ->first(); obtain ERROR: `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`
In ->get(); works

With GET if it works but I only need the first

Example:
`$iduserverified = DB::table('items')->where('id', $request->id)->first();`
`$decadened = json_decode($iduserverified,true);`

$decadened Ahrows:

```json
{#1967 ▼
  +"id": 8
  +"restaurant_id": 1
  +"item_category_id": 1
  +"name": "Falso Teleport"
  +"price": "321.00"
  +"old_price": "0.00"
  +"image": "https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/ifkGKPtSfeo/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CPSFhoYG&rs=AOn4CLCIHKSJbZ265w_iWuFUNsnkWJwzfw"
  +"is_recommended": 0
  +"is_popular": 0
  +"is_new": 1
  +"created_at": "2021-06-17 18:07:22"
  +"updated_at": "2021-06-17 19:00:43"
  +"desc": "<p>3</p>"
  +"placeholder_image": null
  +"is_active": 1
  +"is_veg": null
  +"order_column": null
  +"user_id": "3"
}
```

With ->get(); I don't get any error from json decode and it works but I just need to get the first table ->first();

With ->get(); cast and it works

```json
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1761 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1967 ▼
      +"id": 8
      +"restaurant_id": 1
      +"item_category_id": 1
      +"name": "Falso Teleport"
      +"price": "321.00"
      +"old_price": "0.00"
      +"image": "https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/ifkGKPtSfeo/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CPSFhoYG&rs=AOn4CLCIHKSJbZ265w_iWuFUNsnkWJwzfw"
      +"is_recommended": 0
      +"is_popular": 0
      +"is_new": 1
      +"created_at": "2021-06-17 18:07:22"
      +"updated_at": "2021-06-17 19:00:43"
      +"desc": "<p>3</p>"
      +"placeholder_image": null
      +"is_active": 1
      +"is_veg": null
      +"order_column": null
      +"user_id": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to `json_decode()` the result from your query? are you trying to convert the object to an array?

Comment: Hello I need obtain "user_id" value

Comment: `$iduserverified` is an object so you can access the property like this: `$iduserverified->user_id`

Comment: Use and get error: Property [user_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: I think you are using `->get()`, try changing to `->first()`

Comment: You are absolutely right friend I forgot to change the get by giving it control + z.
Thank you very much if you can put it as an answer to choose it as resolved. Greetings and thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel

```
->get()
```

Returns a collection of data based on your query. (collections are like arrays, they contain multiple Model instances)

On the other hand:

```
->first()
```

Returns only the first row of the resulting query, which means the result is NOT an array, but instead a Model instance, so you don't need to json_decode it, it's already a model, you can simple use it like so.

```
$iduserverified = DB::table('items')->where('id', $request->id)->first();
$itemName = $iduserverified->name; // assuming the item model has name.
```